# Moving useSelector to a helper function or custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm making a few `useSelector` calls, which return arrays used to populate the `HIERARCHY` object.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const one = useSelector(getArrayByName("Name1"));
  const two = useSelector(getArrayByName("Name2"));
  const three = useSelector(getArrayByName("Name3"));

  const HIERARCHY = {
    Levels: {
      Name1: one.map(({ Name }) => Name),
      Name2: two.map(({ Name }) => Name),
      Name3: three.map(({ Name }) => Name)
    },
  };

  // Use HIERARCHY

  return ( … )
}
```

However, this is quite annoying to repeat in different components. Ideally, I'd like to store `HIERARCHY` once, in a helper file or custom hook, and import the populated version of `HIERARCHY` into any component.

I'm not sure how to structure this custom hook or helper file, since the functional component which contains the `useSelector` calls returns `JSX`, and not the populated `JavaScript` object. Any ideas how I'd extract the `useSelector` calls and population of the `HIERARCHY` object to an external file?

**What I want:**

```
import { HIERARCHY } from "./hierarchy_helper.js";

const MyComponent = () => {
  // Use HIERARCHY

  return ( … )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A custom hook is a function (traditionally starts with use...) that can return anything you want (in your case, the HIERARCHY object) and also call other hooks inside it. There are examples in the docs:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

In your case, you can do something like this:

useMyCustomHook.js

```
const useMyCustomHook= () => {
  const one = useSelector(getArrayByName("Name1"));
  const two = useSelector(getArrayByName("Name2"));
  const three = useSelector(getArrayByName("Name3"));

  const HIERARCHY = useMemo({
    Levels: {
      Name1: one.map(({ Name }) => Name),
      Name2: two.map(({ Name }) => Name),
      Name3: three.map(({ Name }) => Name)
    },
  }, [one, two, three]);

  return HIERARCHY;
}
```

MyComponent.jsx

```
const MyComponent = () => {

  const HIERARCHY = useMyCustomHook();

  // Use HIERARCHY

  return ( … )
}
```